# How to create parameter for request body for calling api if parameters required nested info to pass

Tags: ios, swift

I have to create request body for calling api which have nested dictionary formate to pass parameter. I am unable to create parameter

parameter should be in below format

```
        let parameters: [[String: Any]] = [
        "contributionIds":[
            "ms.vss-tfs-web.project-members-data-provider-verticals"
        ],
        "dataProviderContext": [
            "properties": [
                "sourcePage": [
                    "url":"https://xxx.visualstudio.com/abc%20abc",
                    "routeId":"ms.vss-tfs-web.project-overview-route",
                    "routeValues": [
                        "project":"abc",
                        "controller":"Apps",
                        "action":"ContributedHub",
                        "serviceHost":"2e1bc96a-9bac-4e6e-9e33-eb460123a138 (xxxxx)"
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

Above data need to post to api for get response from API

Getting an error

```
  Contextual type '[[String : Any]]' cannot be used with dictionary literal
```

Comment: You need to send the dictionary in params of your POST api?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you’ve written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya no i just want to know how to create parameter for post above info to API

Comment: @iPeter yes i try to post via dictionary but getting an error Contextual type '[[String : Any]]' cannot be used with dictionary literal

Comment: What you have declared is an array of dictionary. Try using [String:Any] instead or  you don't need to specify the type at all because swift will automatically identify it's type if you define it correctly.

Comment: @iPeter thanks for help it's working thanks a lot again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove type notation [[String: Any]] because you are specifying wrong notation based on your structure type notation is [String: Any]. if you will not define type notation then that is fine as well. 
Try Below Solution,

```
let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        "contributionIds":[
            "ms.vss-tfs-web.project-members-data-provider-verticals"
        ],
        "dataProviderContext": [
            "properties": [
                "sourcePage": [
                    "url":"https://xxx.visualstudio.com/VSO%20Client",
                    "routeId":"ms.vss-tfs-web.project-overview-route",
                    "routeValues": [
                        "project":"VSO Client",
                        "controller":"Apps",
                        "action":"ContributedHub",
                        "serviceHost":"2e1bc96a-9bac-4e6e-9e33-eb460123a138 (xxxx)"
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

OR

```
let parameters = [
        "contributionIds":[
            "ms.vss-tfs-web.project-members-data-provider-verticals"
        ],
        "dataProviderContext": [
            "properties": [
                "sourcePage": [
                    "url":"https://xxx.visualstudio.com/VSO%20Client",
                    "routeId":"ms.vss-tfs-web.project-overview-route",
                    "routeValues": [
                        "project":"VSO Client",
                        "controller":"Apps",
                        "action":"ContributedHub",
                        "serviceHost":"2e1bc96a-9bac-4e6e-9e33-eb460123a138 (xxxx)"
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]  as [String : Any]
```